# pandas - 'weird' dataframe format

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

i have a script to drop duplicate timings based on HH:MM, and sum it. but the weird thing is.... 
1. output dataframe seem to have **'Name: Time, dtype: object'** below it.

2. no column name for my summed time

3. i **cant seem to add new column** properly
pls tell me what is happening....!

```
dataset:

Time      Filename
12:00:00  file1.txt
12:01:00  file1.txt
12:02:11  file1.txt
12:01:50  file2.txt
12:02:11  file2.txt
12:01:50  file3.txt
12:02:11  file3.txt
12:03:50  file3.txt


output:
Filename
file1.txt     3
file2.txt     2
file3.txt     3
Name: Time, dtype: object
```

so far this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path(r"C:\\Users\\CL\\Desktop\\Script") # path to your folder
files = list(folder.rglob("*.txt")) #get all the txt file
df = pd.DataFrame()
pattern = r"(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})" #pattern to read

for file in files:
    _df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype=str, names=['Time'])
    _df['Filename'] = os.path.split(file)[-1]
    df = df.append(_df)  
    filtered_df = df[df.Time.str.match(pattern)]

#sum non-duplicate timing   
new_df = filtered_df.groupby("Filename")["Time"].apply(lambda d: d.str[:5].nunique())

#WEIRD output when i testing to add new column
new_df['Filename'] = filtered_df['Filename']

print(new_df)
```

```
'weird' output after adding new col:

Filename
1.txt                                                    3
2.txt                                                    2
3.txt                                                    3
Filename        2      2.txt
5      2.txt
2     11...
Name: Duration, dtype: object
```

---

```
update edits 12/9/21

import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path(r"C:\\Users\\CL\\Desktop\\Script") # path to your folder
files = list(folder.rglob("*.txt")) #get all the txt file
df = pd.DataFrame()
pattern = r"(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})" #pattern to read

for file in files:
    _df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype=str, names=['Time'])
    _df['Filename'] = os.path.split(file)[-1]
    _df['Path'] = "_".join(file.parts[-5:]) #new code - to get file path
    df = df.append(_df)  
    filtered_df = df[df.Time.str.match(pattern)]

new_df = filtered_df.groupby(["Filename","Path"])["Duration"].apply(lambda d: d.str[:5].nunique()).reset_index()



df.to_csv('new_df.csv', index=False) #saved in python folder
```

```
output on jupyter
   Filename  Duration      Path
0  1.txt         3         2021_01_01_cat_1.txt
1  2.txt         2         2021_01_01_cat_2.txt
2  3.txt         3         2021_01_01_cat_3.txt
```

```
output on csv

#shows unfiltered data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you face is owing to the resulting `dataframe` is NOT a Pandas dataframe but a Pandas Series.

You can try to get your result as dataframe by either:

1. adding `as_index=False` to your `.groupby` statement, or
2. `reset_index()` after it:

```
new_df = filtered_df.groupby("Filename", as_index=False)["Time"].apply(lambda d: d.str[:5].nunique())
```

or

```
new_df = filtered_df.groupby("Filename")["Time"].apply(lambda d: d.str[:5].nunique()).reset_index()
```

Comment: Seabean, when i tried to add new column eg. " new_df['Date] = new_df['Filename] it give the error 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis' .... any idea how can i fix this? thank you

Comment: @panzers  Are you sure you are copying column within the same dataframe ?  That is, copy from `new_df` to `new_df` ?    I run this code with your sample data without problem.  There should not be any problem copying within the same dataframe too.  Please check.

Comment: i think so.. pls see my edited post i will add more detail

Comment: @panzers  Your code is actually not copying from the same dataframe as you said in the previous comment. It's copying  from `filtered_df` to `new_df`.   This kind of error is owing to `new_df` is referencing to a fragment of `filtered_df`.  You can resolve this by making `new_df` a brand new copy of dataframe.  Try add `new_df = new_df.copy()` before the copy statement `new_df['Date'] = filtered_df['Filename']`

Comment: ahh... no wonder. sorry about that. thank you for ur help!

Comment: @panzers  So, all problem solved, right ?

Comment: Hi Seabean, sorry to trouble, hmm.. i tried adding one col (file path).. but the output (new_df) doesn't show my Path col.. not sure why.. pls see edited code

Comment: @panzers  Your `new_df` is aggregated based only on the column `Duration` of `filtered_df`.  It did not get access to the data on the column `Path` at all.  Thus, not found on it.

Comment: @panzers  If you want to aggregate more than one column, you have to specify more than one column after `groupby()` (or don't specify columns at all if you want to aggregate all columns).   In this case, you also need to specify different functions to aggreage.  i.e. the the apply and lambda functions need to handle for each column differently, unless they can be all handled alike.

Comment: @panzers  If there is further question regarding your new codes, you can post new questions to let other members to answer you also.  I may not be around here all the time.

Comment: ahh okay, i managed to include Path inside the  Groupby . thanks!!

Comment: the 'Duration' output on my jupyter shows the right output, but when i export it out a csv,  it shows unfiltered dataset. any idea how i can fix this? pls see edited post

Comment: @panzers  Please post your new questions for other members to help you quickly.  I'm not around with my computer and can't answer you quickly.  Also, I can't support you indefinitely for your future problems. Please understand.